# Python and Apache Pig: Passing Arguments/Parameters by File?

Tags: python, parameters, hadoop, arguments, apache-pig

Cite: [Apache Pig ParameterSubstitution](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution)

This is sort of a two-fold question. I have a Python script that I pass parameters to, which in turn runs Pig scripts with the passed parameters.

Apache Pig 0.8.1 does not support white spaces in command line parameters (at some point in the future my company may be able to update to 0.9.x where it is supported). However, **does a Pig 0.8.1 Parameter File (`param_file`) support white space?**

My end goal is that I want to create a Python file that contains default variables. Is there a better way: **should I read in the Python argument file via `eval()`?** I haven't come across any better solution as of yet. If I choose to, I can dual-use this file as a set of Pig parameters, since both use similar syntax standards. Or, I will write the parameters to a file and run the Pig script off of that.

Comment: Pig isn't something that needs 'installing' on your cluster - it handles adding itself to the classpath for you job so I'm not sure why you can't just download the latest version of pig and go from there.

Comment: This is beside the point.